# Help drying polyurethane sealent top coat

Tags: drying

I've used a polyurethane water sealant coating for concrete that is called (vulkem 951 part A ) and it was supposed to mixed with part b the catalyst that starts the drying process but do to a miscommunication it was not ....the people from the company that makes it said it has to be removed as it won't ever dry ...we've removed as much as possible and also tried rolling the catalyst or (part b ) on top but it seems to have done little to nothing as the area is still tacky and wet and it's been over a week since it's been rolled out ...imagine a gooey grey paint spread out over a whole balcony that just won't dry and apparently will never dry ....that's my problem any help would be great ...I was thinking maybe ferric chloride powder  or concrete dust and roll it in to the paint substance ? not sure how safe it is for me to personal use ferric chloride ....please help
Best regards
A nervous maintenance man

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: Not a chemist, and I'm not familiar with the specific polyurethane you are using. Although I've worked with urethane and epoxies a bit, you should probably get a second & third opinion.

A ***careful*** application of heat should help soften the material, hopefully enough to mix with the catalyst.  It might not cure properly but it could at least clear up the sticky situation without resorting to throwing on more chemicals. I've had luck with applying a hair dryer to epoxy that was insufficiently catalyzed. A heat gun might be too hot and even a hair dryer should be kept back at least a few inches from the surface. For my application, the heat helped the process along, however, you must be **careful not to burn it** and **wear a respirator rated for organic solvents** because  it will almost certainly out-gas some pretty toxic fumes when you heat it up.